# Circular dependency for LazyServiceLoader was found for instance `UserService`

Tags: zend-framework2, circular-dependency, zend-servicemanager

In Zend Framework 2,

I have a controller class `UserController`

- `UserController` is dependent on `UserService`
- `UserService` is dependent on `UserChangedListener`
- `UserChangedListener` is dependent on `SomeOtherClass`
- `SomeOtherClass` is dependent on `UserService`

So here my `UserController` and `SomeOtherClass` are dependent on `UserService`.

I am getting error :

> Circular dependency for LazyServiceLoader was found for instance
>   `UserService`

The above error (i.e. Circular dependency for LazyServiceLoader) occurred when I injected `SomeOtherClass` in `UserChangedListener`

And I have

> "zendframework/zend-servicemanager": "^2.7.5 || ^3.0.3",

**UserControllerFactory.php**

```
class UserControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $container = $container->getServiceLocator();

        return new UserController(
            $container->get(UserService::class)
        );
    }

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        return $this($serviceLocator, UserController::class);
    }

}
```

**UserServiceFactory.php**

```
class UserServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $service = new UserService(
            $container->get(UserRepository::class)
        );

        $eventManager = $service->getEventManager();
        $eventManager->attach($container->get(UserChangedListener::class));

        return $service;
    }

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        return $this($serviceLocator, UserService::class);
    }
}
```

**UserChangedListenerFactory.php**

```
class UserChangedListenerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $container = $container->getServiceLocator();

        return new UserChangedListener(
            $container->get(SomeOtherClass::class)
        );
    }

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        return $this($serviceLocator, UserChangedListener::class);
    }
}
```

**SomeOtherClassFactory.php**

```
class SomeOtherClassFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $rootLocator = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();

        return new SomeOtherClass(
            $rootLocator->get(UserService::class)
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a legitimate circular dependency with `UserService`. The error message is telling you that the `UserService` cannot be created without the `UserService`.

This is really a problem introduced by the good practice of using dependency injection via the `__construct` method. By doing so, ZF2 will **eager** load a very large object graph into memory, when you have lots of related 'services' that have complex nested relationships you are bound to have circular dependencies.

ZF2 does offer [Lazy Services](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.service-manager.lazy-services.html) as a solution to delay the instantiation of certain objects that as the developer you will need to decide on which ones (I would suggest `UserChangedListener`).

Alternatively to update your code, you could *move the registration of the listener code outside of the `UserServiceFactory`* and into the `Module::onBootstrap()` method.

```
namespace User;

class Module
{   
    public function onBootstrap(EventInterface $event)
    {
        $serviceManager = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();

        // Create the user service first
        $userService = $serviceManager->get(UserService::class);

        $listener = $serviceManager->get(UserChangedListener::class);

        // The create and attach the listener after user service has been created.
        $userService->getEventManager()->attach($listener);
    }

}
```

This would be required if you are using the 'aggregate' listeners. For simple event listeners you can also use the `SharedEventManager` which would prevent the overhead of loading the `UserService` in the above example.

Comment: It's an old response but keep in mind that using `onBootstrap()` would create UserService and UserChangedListener on every request! Not only when it needed!

Answer (score 0):

- `UserService` is dependent on `SomeOtherClass` through
  `UserChangedListener`
- `SomeOtherClass` is dependent on `UserService`

So basically for creation `UserService` you need first create `SomeOtherClass` instance, but for create it you need `UserService` instance to be created already.

I'm not sure about your architecture, but according to class names it looks bit wrong that you attach `UserChangedListener` in `UserService`.
Probably `UserService` should only fire events, and shouldn't know anything about listeners for this events. But again - that just idea, and for good answer you need to explain this dependencies bit more.